# Hibernate predicate to get children based on parent

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following structure:

```
@Entity
class Parent {
  @Id
  int id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  List<Child> children;

}

@Entity
public class Child {    
  @Id
  int id;

  @ManyToOne
  Parent parent;  
}
```

I want to get children based on a specific parent id. As I want to paginate the result I want to build predicate for children and not just fetch parent and get all the children this way.

So, I imagining predicate like this for the Child query:

```
builder.equal(root.get("parent.id"), parentId);
```

But this obviously will not work. So, what is the right way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parent.id` is not a property name, but a property path. If you read the java doc, you will see that `Path#get` requires a property name though. So to fix this, use `root.get("parent").get("id")`